# Load other files (from outside public_html) under index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I wanted to load every page under index.php with a simple `index.php?do=login`

For example when the link `index.php?do=login` or `/login/` is opened, the file login.php is loaded (from outside `public_html`), and so everything is done under index.php instead of having a separate php file in `public_html` for each action!

This is what I've tried already, am I doing it okay? (I'm not sure if what I'm doing has any security vulnerabilities, so please kindly advise)

**index.php**

```
<?php

// application path (outside public_html)
define('FILESPATH', APP.'../application/actions/');

// Default file
$file_name = 'home_page';

// e.g. index.php?do=login
if(isset($_GET['do'])){
    $file_name = rtrim($_GET['do'],'/');
}

// Set file path
$fpath = FILESPATH."{$file_name}.php";

// Make sure user input has valid characters
if(preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/', $file_name) !== 1 OR ! file_exists($fpath)){
    // Error
    require_once('404.php');
    die();
}

// Load the do=file
require_once($fpath);

// Nothing more comes in index.php
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

// Load template file header
require_once('header_template.php');


//
// Stuff that happens in login.php
// Like checking if username has valid characters then searching for it with pdo in db,
// password_verify(), etc...
//


// After the stuff done above load login html template
require_once('login_template.php');

// Load template footer
require_once('footer_template.php');
```

**.htaccess**

To run with `site.com/login/` etc instead of `site.com?do=login`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule   ^((?s).*)$ index.php?do=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is simply asking us to review the code and it should therefore be posted in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm simply asking what is the best practice to load files under `index.php` from outside `public_html` and also included what I've tried already :(

Comment: I understand, but SO is for when you're having some specific _issue_ with your code that you just can't solve yourself. What you are asking is for us to simply review your code  and come with advice. That's off-topic here but on-topic over at Code Review so I would recommend that you post this question there instead.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a router. Instead of reinventing the wheel I would suggest you rather look at existing ones which have already seen some usage and testing.

[Respect/Rest](http://respect.github.io/Rest/docs/) is lightweight, versatile and very easy to use.

```php
use Respect\Rest\Router;

$r3 = new Router('/index.php');

// endpoint: /index.php/
$r3->get('/', function() {
    return 'Hello World';
});

// endpoint: /index.php/login
$r3->any('/login', function() {
    // use $_POST data to validate user
    return 'Login Success';
});

// endpoint: /index.php/item/123
$r3->get('/item/*', function($id) {
    $item = $db->fetchItem($id);
    return json_encode($item);
});
```

Doesn't get much easier than that... nJoy!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I checked the repository but it seems the last update was 3 years ago and it is not very active either :( If you are a professional PHP coder, could you please kindly check if you see any issues/vulnerabilities on my code?

Comment: Yes indeed it was finished 3 years ago and still works like a charm. The guys have been really busy with the Respect/Validation menu of late but I use it in all my apps, works great for ajax calls.

Comment: I had a look yesterday but didn't see any alarms go off, all looks good.